# ALT + TAB (Task Switcher) in eWAM

Tags: ewam

How to switch to a different task, or view the previously opened windows in eWAM without using the mouse? I have tried ALT+TAB it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the "modal" nature of Wynsure it is often not advised to switch between screens when in a multi step process for sub process.  However, when relevant you can use **Ctrl+F6** to cycle between open windows as an alternative to selecting them through he "View" menu with the mouse. Here is a list of the most popular Wynsure shortcuts

- **Ctrl+F2** to insert the current date in any date field (must be active)
- **Ctrl+F4** to close a window
- **Ctrl+F6** to cycle between open windows
- **Ctrl+F10** to toggle a window from "maximized" in the workbench or "restored" as a separate window in from the the application.